# Cannot access WSO2 EMM Store/Publisher on localhost

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I am trying to run wso2emm instance on windows 8 laptop and can access EMM dashboard fine. But get 500 error while accessing publisher and a blank page when I try to acess store. Not finding anything in the logs. Console dispalys following message:

```
[2015-04-19 22:23:21,585]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.internal.APIKeyMgtServiceCompo nent} -  Setting default carbon host for thrift key management service: mdm.asus.com 
[2015-04-19 22:23:21,601]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.internal.APIKeyMgtServiceCompo nent} -  Started thrift key mgt service at port:10397 
[2015-04-19 22:23:21,703]  INFO {JAGGERY.config.app:js} -  Publisher URL : http://mdm.asus.co m:9763/publisher
```

I saw a post where someone suggested to use domain and host name in carbon config so I am using a dummy host name mapped to my local ip via host file but not luck. Copy of same code on Amazon EC2 works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure both  and  elements in Carbon.xml file to correctly map the EMM server to a host name.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response!. I confirmed carbon.xml;emm-config.xml and sso-idp-config.xml have hostname instead of localhost. Is there anything else am I am missing?

Comment: Why do you have a blank space in publisher url "/mdm.asus.co m"? 
[2015-04-19 22:23:21,703]  INFO {JAGGERY.config.app:js} -  Publisher URL : http://mdm.asus.co m:9763/publisher

Comment: Further can you try by configuring identityProviderURL with including hostname in WSO2_EMM/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/productapistore/site.json and WSO2_EMM/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/productapipublisher/site.json? Please enable debug logs of those jaggery apps by adding "logLevel": "debug" to jaggery.conf files in productapistore and productapipublisher directory.

Comment: The space was copy and pasting error while posting to stackoverflow. I checked and conf files do not have space. Also, made both the changes you suggested but still no luck. I checked the wso2emm-1.1.0\repository\logs\wso2carbon.log file but it still does not have any details. Did not find any other logs. Are there any other log files that I need to check. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: Did you enabled debug logs of apistore and publisher apps as I've mentioned in previous comment? You can see the logs on the cmd itself when running EMM server. We have not tested EMM on a Windows 8 environment yet. So I can not give exact answer for this until it is tested.

Comment: I checked the command prompt but nothing is showing up there. I double checked the config and confirmed debug was enabled. I have it working on Linux box so I think we are OK. May be something related to windows 8. I really appreciate your help and we can consider it close. Thanks, Again!!